# Are there any Lutherans that have a different view about Salvation?

Tags: lutheranism

I read from the following  [link](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/53984/what-is-the-basis-for-lutheran-single-predestination-as-opposed-to-double-prede)

> Lutherans believe that Christ died for the sins of all people and that
>   God wants all people to be saved (see, for example John 3:16, 1 John
>   2:2, 1 Timothy 2:4-6). However, not all people are saved. Why?
>   Lutherans would say that we don't know why. That is, if my first
>   sentence of this paragraph is true, then the logical question is **"why
>   is not everyone saved?"** The Lutheran answer is, "we don't know,
>   because God doesn't tell us."

---

I propose an analogy something like this :

> There are 100 persons is about to drown in the sea. All of them will
>   be surely die if there isn't any salvation team, but still some of
>   them (70 persons) are trying to rescue themselves.
>
> SAR team is coming and throw a life vest for all those 100 persons.
>   Too bad, the one who is trying to rescue themselves still think that
>   they can rescue/save themselves. So, the 70 persons abandon their life
>   vest. The 30 persons grab and put their life jacket.
>
> Q : who are saved (reach the land) at the end ? A : the 30 persons.

Conclusion, even the SAR team is there for all those 100 persons - **because the "stubbornness" of some of them**, so at the end not everyone is saved. (the bold here is the answer of the bold question from the Lutherans above).

My analogy is involving Freewill.
I don't know if Lutheran teaching believes on Freewill or not.
That's why I ask here.

<sub>The analogy can not be applied to the past.
If say in the analogy there are some already dead drowned, then the SAR team coming is too late for the one who already dead :)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Yes,  Lutherans believe in Freewill, but a Lutheran would structure your example a little differently, and have a different interpretation of it. An interpretation consistent with Lutheran theology would be that none of the 100 people can save him or herself, in the words of the Small Catechism

> I believe that I cannot by my own reason or strength believe in Jesus Christ my Lord, or come to Him;  but the Holy Ghost has called me through the Gospel, enlightened me by his gifts, and sanctified and preserved me in the true faith; [Explanation of the 3rd article of the Apostle's Creed].

The SAR in your example is God the Holy Spirit, and the rescue is effected by Jesus' death and resurrection which saves some number of the hundred people you identify. But Lutherans understand that although Jesus' death and resurrection are available to all 100 people in your example,  a few (though we don't know how many, nor do we know who they are) may reject the promised salvation through their exercise of Freewill.

Comment: You wrote : *An interpretation consistent with Lutheran theology would be that **none of the 100 people can save him or herself***. This where I wrote : *All of them will be surely die if there isn't any salvation team*

Comment: You wrote : *a few (though we don't know how many, nor do we know who they are) may reject the promised salvation through their exercise of Freewill*. This where I wrote : *because the "stubbornness" of some of them*. Thank you for your answer brasshat.

Comment: From the link : "why is not everyone saved?" The Lutheran answer is, "we don't know, because God doesn't tell us." IMHO, I think the answer can be *"because some of them think that they can rescue/save themselves"*. :).